# Is there any way to instruct PHP XMLReader to *not* normalize carriage returns in elements

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, xmlreader

I am processing XML with PHP's XMLReader, and I need to preserve white space characters, including carriage returns in the data I am parsing. However, the reader is replacing carriage returns with new line characters. Is there a way to instruct it not to do that?

Answer (score 0):

[`XMLReader`](http://php.net/class.xmlreader) will automatically normalize `\r\n\` to `\n`. Although you want to preserve those, it is actually required by the XML Specification ([2.11 End-of-Line Handling](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-line-ends)).

You can *probably* work around that by afterwards replacing `\n` with `\r\n`.

```
str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $reader->value)
```

For white space handling `XMLReader` passes whitespace unaltered and differs between `WHITESPACE` and `SIGNIFICANT_WHITESPACE` nodes.

Generally speaking, as you need to *"preserve white space characters, including carriage returns in the data"* XML is not the right technology to handle and process your data.

Depending on your use-case you can decide to encode the binary data you have in a way so that it is preserved in XML, e.g. with [`base64_encode`](http://php.net/base64_encode).